# UITableView auto-scrolls simultaneously according to another UITableView

Tags: uitableview, autoscroll, simultaneous

Is it possible to make the effect that :

when I scroll an UITableView, another UITableView auto-scrolls simultaneously according to the UITableView I am moving.

NS: Can't combine the two UITableViews in one UITableView for some reasons...

Thanks.

---

I have found a way and tested.  Just I am not sure if it is a good way.
Perform scrollViewDidScroll of UIScrollViewDelegate like the follows.
But I have to uncheck bouncing effect since it makes the scrollViewDidScroll being called for many times for one scroll...

```
- (void)syncTableViews:(UIScrollView *)whatScrollView
{
    int tmpDesY = whatScrollView.contentOffset.y;
    BOOL tmpNeedSetTv00 = NO;
    BOOL tmpNeedSetTv01 = NO;
    BOOL tmpNeedSetTv02 = NO;

    if(whatScrollView == self.TableView00)
    {
        tmpNeedSetTv01 = YES;
        tmpNeedSetTv02 = YES;
    }
    else if(whatScrollView == self.TableView01)
    {
        tmpNeedSetTv00 = YES;
        tmpNeedSetTv02 = YES;
    }
    else if(whatScrollView == self.TableView02)
    {
        tmpNeedSetTv00 = YES;
        tmpNeedSetTv01 = YES;
    }

    if(tmpNeedSetTv00 == YES)
    {
        [self.TableView00 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.TableView00.contentOffset.x,tmpDesY) animated:NO];
    }    
    if(tmpNeedSetTv01 == YES)
    {
        [self.TableView01 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.TableView01.contentOffset.x,tmpDesY) animated:NO];
    }
    if(tmpNeedSetTv02 == YES)
    {
        [self.TableView02 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.TableView02.contentOffset.x, tmpDesY) animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self syncTableViews:scrollView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An UITableView as for delegate a UIScrollView, adding UIScrollViewDelegate to your class you 
just use :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIScrollView *otherScrollView = (scrollView == self.tableViewHours ) ? self.tableViewDay : self.tableViewHours;
    [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:NO];
}
```

Regards.